# Book about two children who traveled through time using a circle of stones

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, childrens-novel

This book is about 2 children who traveled trough time using a circle of stones similar to Stonehenge.  It was read to me in 5th grade, around 1985. I am having trouble remembering more details.  They had to find a way back home at the end of the story.

Comment: Hm..  It _almost_ reminds me of [The Ancient One](http://tabarron.com/ancient-one) by T. A. Barron, except that was published in 1992, and the Circle of Stones wasn't the method of time travel.

Answer (score 5):

[In the Circle of Time](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0394840291) by Margaret J. Anderson (1979)?

Two children (Jennifer and Robert), standing stones (the Circle of Arden) and time travel.

Appears to be the middle book of a trilogy, occurs between [In the Keep of Time](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0590053795) and [The Mists of Time](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0394865731)

Comment: +1 Added link to Amazon info and info on other novels in the trilogy.

Answer (score 4):

There's a seven episode TV drama, [Children of the Stones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Children_of_the_Stones), that aired on the UK ITV network in Jan/Feb 1977 that has certain elements of your description.  It was novelized (March 1977) in a book of the same name.  The TV series is available on DVD (Amazon, Barnes & Noble, Netflix).  A Kindle edition of the book is available but hardcopy appears to be out of print.

- Set in the village of Milbury which is in the middle of a megalithic stone circle.
- Has two teenage leads, characters are named Mathew and Sandra.
- Involves temporal paradoxes and something called 'time loops'

All the references say it was definitely frightening.  Does that aspect ring a bell ?

Comment: I will have to look at Children of the Stones... It sounds like a possibility.  However, I never saw the movie so it would be the novelized version.  Does anyone else have any other ideas?

Comment: Children of the Stones was fantastic TV and I had the book as well but I don't think it matches. They didn't travel anywhere via the stone circle and didn't have to get home.

Comment: @TheMathemagician - thanks for the feedback.  I think Frock nailed it in his/her answer.

Answer (score 2):

Could be the [Wierdstone of Brisingamen?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Weirdstone_of_Brisingamen) Not sure if the time travel part matches, but there are two kids involved. Susan and Colin are siblings, staying with a friend of their mother while their parents are overseas. Susan's bracelet contains a mysterious stone, the wierdstone of the title, unbeknownts to her until an evil spirit tries to steal it from her. Wizards and prophecies, and an ancient evil, elves, dwarves, and ancient gods, with mixes from norse and celtic mythologies make for an interesting story!