# Quartet of books about a boy discovering a secret passage in a stone circle

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

I read this book at school in the early 1990's. I seem to remember the title being "Summer of [blank]" "Spring of [blank]" etc.

It's centred on a village that has a stone circle. I vaguely remember the boy having an archaeologist father, and travelling through a secret passage in a Stonehenge-like stone circle and discovering another world underneath.

The characters in each book were recurring in each book of the series, but on different points of their time line.

A snake definitely became a major plot point in the later ones (possibly winter and autumn?)
I would really appreciate any one who could even say they've read the books! This has been bothering me for years!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two Children, Circle of Stones](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/34021/book-about-2-children-who-traveled-through-time-using-a-circle-of-stones/34025#34025) ?

Answer (score 3):

The story you describe has a lot in common with the tv serial [Children of the Stones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Children_of_the_Stones), including a stone circle, a scientist father, serpent imagry, and hidden passages.

The story was novelized in 1977, according to Wikipedia.

But I don't believe there was ever a 4-book series based on this story.

Comment: No there was a single book based on the TV series. Fairly certain it wasn't Children of the Stones as many of the details don't match.