# Book series where a group of kids enter a fantasy world through a stone circle

Tags: story-identification, books

This is a book and I believe a book series that I read while in grade school (12/13-ish years ago). There are several things I don't remember about the book(s), like, for example, if I read more than just one.

But here is what I do remember;

- They are a group of kids that travel to a fantasy realm.
- They travel there through a circle of stones on the ground. Like a circle of large pebbles in a circle.
- They defeat a basilisk, the original image of one i.e. the one that's a mix of a snake, dragon, and a rooster, and not the HP snake.

Comment: This doesn't quite match but for some reason this makes me think of the [_Power of Five_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Power_of_Five) series.

Comment: Do you by chance remember if the book was like brand new as you read it or if it was something of an older story?

Comment: @Daarin I think it was relatively new, but it could be several years old for all that I knew at that time

Comment: Could it be _Darkhenge_ by Catherine Fisher?, or maybe one of the answers [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/34021/90788)? or one in this [list of stories with a circle of stones](https://www.goodreads.com/list/show/85897.Stone_Circles)?